# Grouped bar chart R using counts table

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

How would I make a grouped bar chart using a table of counts i.e.

```
    v1  v2  v3  v4  v5
a   0   0   1   1   1
b   6   1   12  9   8
c   4   1   4   4   3
d   1   0   0   1   0
e   2   2   0   2   2
```

Where the x labels would be a-e and the 5 grouped bars of each of a-e would be of given height of v1-v5 and colors corresponding to V1-v5.

Comment: `barplot(t(dat), beside=TRUE, col=1:5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reshape your data, here is how you can do it with `tidyr` and `ggplot`:

```
library(tidyr); library(ggplot2);

ggplot(gather(df, group, count, -x), aes(x = x, y = count, fill = group)) + 
       geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Where I added an x column which corresponds to your original rowname for transformation purpose and the `gather` function transform your original data frame from wide to long format:

```
  x v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
1 a  0  0  1  1  1
2 b  6  1 12  9  8
3 c  4  1  4  4  3
4 d  1  0  0  1  0
5 e  2  2  0  2  2
```